# system(cmd) fails if cmd includes # character

Tags: vimscript

I have been trying the https://github.com/ngemily/vim-vp4 plugin for integrating Perforce version control commands into Vim.

The `Vp4Diff` command fails for me.  I tracked it down to a step where a `system(cmd)` function was being called when `cmd = "p4 fstat-T headrev <filename>#have"`.

The problem is actually not caused by Perforce.  I find that any cmd containing a `#` character will fail.

```
:call system('touch #this')
```

...but I get an error:

```
E484: Can't open file /tmp/vx0yoZZ/1
```

I'm using Vim 8.2.1001.  This happens for both tcsh shell and bash.  It also happens when running `vim --clean`.

I'm disapointed the error message wasn't "U Can't Touch #This"

Comment: `#` indicates a comment in the shell (where that is running). You can quote it... `system("touch '#this'")` ...which will prevent its interpretation as a comment char.

Comment: ...escaping it should work, too, FYI ... `system('touch \#this')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the `#` is necessary for the shell to not consider it a comment.

That can be done with the `escape()` function:

```
let cmd = 'touch #this'
call system(escape(cmd, '#'))
```

The `shellescape()` function does **not** work here because a pair of single quotes would surround both words together, as if `'touch \#this'` was a single Linux command.

Comment: Well, it'll work if you do `system('touch ' . shellescape('#this'))` which is a perfectly reasonable approach although `fnameescape('#this')` is probably a better choice.